# Storing Nx2 matrices returned by mvnrnd in a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am using a mvnrnd to get two columns of N picks from two correlated normal distributions. I want to use mvnrnd Z times and store them in a 1xZ vector where each entry is the Nx2 matrix returned by mvnrnd.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you can't store a matrix in a vector entry, vector entry is a *scalar*. however, you can store a matrix in a 1D cell array entry:

```
N = 50;
Z = 3;
% pre allocate cell array
C = cell(1,Z);
for ii = 1:Z
    % generate your Nx2 random matrix
    M = rand(N,2);
    % store the matrix in a cell
    C{ii} = M;
end
disp(C)

C = 
    [50×2 double]    [50×2 double]    [50×2 double]
```